# a loop in own Thread

Tags: ios, loops, xcode4

I want to show some picture with a waiting of 2sec before showing the other.
So i tried to do it with the good old C99 : sleep(300) but the UI does not update.

The second thing I tried was:
1. create the method in his own thread

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(gameIt) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

1. Then sleep in the Method with:

   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

But the same problem, the UI does not update. 
What do I make wrong? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you `sleep` on the main thread, you will stall the UI.

You may have some luck with NSThread's class method `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`. You'll have to keep some context so that each invocation of your method will know what to do, but this will not stall your UI and it will give you the 3 second (or whatever) interval you're looking for.

Comment: I'd make that more generic.... anytime you are using 'sleep()' you are doing it wrong. ;)

Comment: Agreed. The OP mentioned that the UI doesn't update when he uses sleep, so I phrased my warning in that context. :-) But I like how you put it! +1!

Answer (score 0):

Run your processing on the background thread, but when you edit the UI you need to performSelectorOnMainThread

```
[view performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```